# Error about a class I don't even have

Tags: c++, ios, macos, class, netbeans

This is my error

> "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
>   "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/practice3
>   make[2]: *** No rule to make target `newClass.cpp', needed by`build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newClass.o'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
>   make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

a few minutes before making this program I did make a class called newClass, by accident, but then I deleted it and I cannot find it on my computer(mac) at all.

Here is my program if it is inflicting this error message at all, which I don't think it should do at all as it doesn't call out the newClass class at all.

**main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include "People.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Birthday birthObj(1,28,2000);

    People sebA("Sebastian A", birthObj);
    sebA.printInfo();


}
```

**Birthday.h**

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H
using namespace std;

class Birthday {
public:
    Birthday(int m, int d, int y);
    void printDate();
private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

};

#endif
```

**Birthday.cpp**

```
#include "Birthday.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Birthday::Birthday(int m, int d, int y) {
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;

}

void Birthday::printDate() {
    cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
}
```

**People.h**

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H

#include <string>
#include "Birthday.h"
using namespace std;

class People {
public:
    People(string x, Birthday bo); 
    void printInfo();
private:
    string name;
    Birthday dateOfBirth; // dateOfBirth is an object

};

#endif
```

**People.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Birthday.h"
#include "People.h"
using namespace std;

People::People(string x, Birthday bo)
: name(x), dateOfBirth(bo)
{


}

void People::printInfo(){
    cout << name << " was born on ";
    dateOfBirth.printDate();
}
```

Comment: Its a makefile problem. You're c++ is useless to us.

Comment: Ah okay, what do you want me to add?

Comment: No idea, some sort of configuration with Netbeans, but i don't use Netbeans.

Comment: Oh right, I will check the options of Netbeans, thank you :)

Comment: I can't find it, if anyone else can help me. I'd be very grateful :)

Comment: Its a makefile issue. Could you share your makefile. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `make clean` will fix it. Or at least just explicitly `rm build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newClass.o`.

Basically, when you created your class and compiled, you got a `.o` for it which depends on it. But once you deleted the class, there is probably some rule in your makefile like

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) ...
```

So `make` is trying to build `newClass.o` which depends on `newClass.cpp` which doesn't exist so you don't have a rule to make it, hence the error. If you just delete the now-unnecessary object file, everything should compile happily.

Comment: Yes! Works now, thanks a lot :) Was a really stupid bug I had no idea how to fix.